# How to trigger event when the panorama item is loaded in c# windows phone?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am new to c# and windows phone programming, I am developing a app in which I want to show message box with different messages for each panorama item, I know how to trigger event for pivot item but I am stuck with this panorama item events.

**Requirement:**

Initially panorama item should display "one" in message box and while swiping to second panorama item it should display "two" in message box.

Comment: shouldn't be far different from pivot item. What have you tried?

Comment: private void loginpivt(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item == loginpivot)
            {
                ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
                 
            }
            else
            {
                ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
            }

Comment: You should use panorama's selection change event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you are having 4 panorama items:

```
 private void mainPanorama_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mainPanorama.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
               //Put your message
            }
            else if (mainPanorama.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                //Put your message
            }
            else if (mainPanorama.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                //Put your message
            }
            else if (mainPanorama.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {
                //Put your message
            }

        }
```

Comment: what is mainPanorama in (mainPanorama.SelectedIndex == 1) and mainPanorama_SelectionChanged_1 in function is it name..

Comment: Actually this is the name of panorama item which i am having by default you could put your own name ...

Comment: you could do it by panorama item name

Comment: Thank you ..Any way you helped me..mainPanorama is the name of the panorama and upvoted for that